# wamp on windows7 - This webpage is not available

Tags: windows-7, localhost, wamp

I have been using WAMP on my localhost for a few weeks and since this morning it doesn't work.
This is the error I get when loading localhost: This webpage is not available.

Firefox error is: Unable to connect. Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at localhost.

If I try to load phpmyadmin from the wamp menu, it will return the same error.

This is my apache error log:

```
[Mon Sep 15 23:10:36.435939 2014] [ssl:warn] [pid 2064:tid 308] AH01873: Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]
[Mon Sep 15 23:10:36.557946 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2064:tid 308] AH00455: Apache/2.4.9 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.0.1g PHP/5.5.12 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Sep 15 23:10:36.557946 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2064:tid 308] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC11 Server built: Mar 16 2014 12:42:59
[Mon Sep 15 23:10:36.557946 2014] [core:notice] [pid 2064:tid 308] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\wamp\\bin\\apache\\apache2.4.9\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.9'
[Mon Sep 15 23:10:36.559946 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2064:tid 308] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 4796
[Mon Sep 15 23:10:37.751014 2014] [ssl:warn] [pid 4796:tid 208] AH01873: Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]
[Mon Sep 15 23:10:37.779016 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4796:tid 208] AH00354: Child: Starting 64 worker threads.
```

The day before having these problems I followed some instructions on how to make localhost load faster. I got to these instructions by simply googling "localhost slow" but I don't have the exact links to these things.

I do recall though, having disabling IPV6 (which I think is causing some problems now) in the regedit, by adding DisabledComponents with the value fffffff to the registry.
I've already deleted that key.

I also played around with the host file (which I believe I have reverted back to the original).
I currently only have one localhost in it (127.0.0.1). The rest are commented out.

If anyone needs more info, please let me know.

edit: I forgot to mention that when I run google app engine server, my localhost works fine with GAE applications but still doesn't budge for WAMP.

Comment: Have you tried clearing the cache ?

Comment: @AIL IF you mean flushing the DNS cache, yes, I've done that. Oher caches, no.